# xml_nodeset to tibble, one row per xml_nodeset (item)

Tags: r, purrr, rvest, xml2, node-set

I have a complicated xml file with items as 1st child nodes. The items can have different structure and some of the attributes are missing in some of them. I need to store one item (nodeset) in tibble row, so that I keep track on missing attributes and write a function handling all variants.

I found a solution of the first step by Felix Ebert:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253021/how-to-extract-xml-attr-and-xml-text-on-different-levels-with-xml2-and-purrr](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I copy part of the code here:

```
xml <- xml2::read_xml("input/example.xml")
rows <- xml %>% xml_find_all("//xmlsubsubnode")
rows_df <- data_frame(node = rows)
```

Function data_frame was depreciated and I got error messages if I replace it with

```
tibble()
as_tibble()
data.frame()
```

With "tibble" I get following ERROR:

```
df_articles <- tibble(item = xml_articles)
Error:
! All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
✖ Column `item` is a `xml_nodeset` object.
Backtrace:
1. tibble::tibble(item = xml_articles)
2. tibble:::tibble_quos(xs, .rows, .name_repair)
3. tibble:::check_valid_col(res, col_names[[j]], j)
4. tibble:::check_valid_cols(set_names(list(x), name))
```

I would be grateful if anybody can update the original post.

Comment: If you can post a sample `xml` file it will be a lot easier to help you. It appears you need to convert `rows` to a vector. Maybe use `xml_attr`? `rows_df <- rows %>% map_df(xml_attr)`

Comment: Dear @pgcudahy , the structure of xml would be as below. There is a root node "items" containing 2 different types of those items (i.e. p_item or e_items). I want to split the large xml to dataframe, where each item will occupy single row. Later I want to apply a function that will extract info for each item to corresponding column. ' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<p_item>
    <id>id1</id>
</p_item>
<e_item>
    <e_id>id2</e_id>
</e_item>
<p_item>
    <id>id3</id>
    <e_id>id3</e_id>
</p_item>
</items> '